# Validação de datas de input type date com jquery

Tags: jquery

O código abaixo para comparação de datas funciona para condição if `>=` e else.

```js
function validaDatas(){
    var dataInicial = new Date($("input[name='datainicial']").val());
    var dataFinal = new Date($("input[name='datafinal']").val());
    if (!dataInicial || !dataFinal) return false;
    if (dataInicial >= dataFinal) {
        alert("dataInicial maior que DataFinal ou datas iguais");
    }else{
     alert("dataInicial menor que DataFinal");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="return validaDatas()">
    <div>
    <label>Data inicial:</label>
    <input type="date" name="datainicial" />
    <label>Data Final:</label>
    <input type="date" name="datafinal" />
    </div>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Porém se colocar um  `else if` separando a condição de datas iguais `==` o script  não funciona nessa condição

```js
function validaDatas(){
    var dataInicial = new Date($("input[name='datainicial']").val());
    var dataFinal = new Date($("input[name='datafinal']").val());
    if (!dataInicial || !dataFinal) return false;
    if (dataInicial > dataFinal) {
        alert("dataInicial maior que DataFinal");
    }else if (dataInicial == dataFinal){
     alert("dataInicial igual a DataFinal");
    }else{
     alert("dataInicial menor que DataFinal");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="return validaDatas()">
    <div>
    <label>Data inicial:</label>
    <input type="date" name="datainicial" />
    <label>Data Final:</label>
    <input type="date" name="datafinal" />
    </div>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**PORQUE?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O objeto `Date` pode ser utilizado com os operadores >, <, <= ou >=. Já os operadores ==, !=, === e !=== exigem que você use `date.getTime()`.

Segue seu código ajustado, e você pode ler mais sobre o objeto Date aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```js
function validaDatas(){
    var dataInicialSplit = $("input[name='datainicial']").val().split('-');
    var dataFinalSplit = $("input[name='datafinal']").val().split('-');
    var dataInicial = new Date(dataInicialSplit[0], dataInicialSplit[1] - 1, dataInicialSplit[2]);
    var dataFinal = new Date(dataFinalSplit[0], dataFinalSplit[1] - 1, dataFinalSplit[2]);
    if (!dataInicial || !dataFinal) return false;
    if (dataInicial.getTime() > dataFinal.getTime()) {
        alert("dataInicial maior que DataFinal");
    }else if (dataInicial.getTime() == dataFinal.getTime()){
     alert("dataInicial igual a DataFinal");
    }else{
     alert("dataInicial menor que DataFinal");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="return validaDatas()">
    <div>
    <label>Data inicial:</label>
    <input type="date" name="datainicial" />
    <label>Data Final:</label>
    <input type="date" name="datafinal" />
    </div>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Obs: A criação de um novo objeto `Date` tem 4 construtores possíveis:

```
new Date()
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

No caso de utilizar uma string, a data computada será relativa ao time zone, e, dependendo do time zone o resultado pode variar.

Para garantir o resultado esperado, recomendo utilizar o 4º construtor citado acima pois garante que a data instanciada será a que for passada por parâmetro.

Para ler mais sobre datas em JavaScript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp
Para ler mais sobre formatos de data em JavaScript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: Diego Marques, muito bom!! Só uma coisa, se você colocar alert(dataInicial)  e alert(dataFinal)   vai ver que embora diga que é horaoficial do Brasil com GMT -3 a data é do dia anterior. Sabe pq?

Comment: Editei a resposta com essas observações :)

Comment: Valeu Diego Marques! Melhor que isso só dois disso :)